# OCI Authorization failed

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

"You don’t have permission to view these resources in this compartment. Try another compartment, or contact your administrator for help." or "Authorization failed or requested resource not found."

I get this message when I go to the instances section, and in addition, the virtual machine I created has stopped working, most likely already deleted. How can I solve this problem? I have been using Free tier for the second month and got this gift

I was quietly using my virtual machine and got some kind of lockdown, without any warnings or alerts.

Answer (score 2):

I created my free tier account today and had the same problem.

I contacted [chat support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3lcY.png) and told me to do the following:
Login from **link you received to login in the welcome email** that you got after registering, in my case the email was "Get Started Now with Oracle Cloud", in **INCOGNITO MODE**.

1- Right click on the login button in the email and copy link address
2- Open a tab in INCOGNITO MODE
3- Paste and login
4- Create instance

I don't know why, but it worked for me. 
I hope it does for you!

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday and this worked for me too. I had to use Edge; Oracle refused complete the process in a private Firefox session.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already upgraded to a paid account, I would suggest going that route. There is no charge to convert and as long as you use [Always Free](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/FreeTier/freetier_topic-Always_Free_Resources.htm) resources you'll never be charged a cent.  If you continue to see issues with the account, you can chat with support or open a ticket using the Help menu in the top right of the console.